# curent language token on block body

Tags: hooks, tokens

what is the token used to get the curent language, I want to use this token on a link in the block body, like that:

```
<a href="/[curent-language]/about-us">About us</a>
```

I find this token `[site:url]` is good, but in default language the link become `//about-us` two slashes, otherwise `/fr/about-us` in the french language(good).

Comment: the token is: [node:language]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this module http://drupal.org/project/token_custom to create your own token, I create a Token Type `Language` that containt my `path` token, the content of this token is the result of the PHP code(use PHP Filter module to include PHP code):

```
<?php 
  global $language;

  return ($language->language === 'en' ? '/' : '/'.$language->language.'/');
?>
```

In the block body, I can use my token like this:

```
<a href="[language:path]about-us">About us</a>
```

---

You can post a comment for any Help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try `<a href="/[node:source:language]/about-us">About us</a>`